# Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW) configuration problems on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, ufw

I've installed UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) from the EPEL repo. When I try to allow connections to a non-default SSH port using `ufw allow 22022/tcp`, it fails with:

> ERROR: problem running

The same error occurs with deny on an arbitrary port.

When I try to change the logging settings using `ufw logging off`, I get:

> ERROR: Could not update running firewall

But UFW is **not** running (I triple checked it with `ufw status` and `systemctl status ufw` and `ps aux | grep ufw`). Any ideas how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors indicate that the firewall is not running. The commands are working nevertheless. You have to start the firewall in order to make the errors go away: `systemctl start ufw`.

But **be careful** if it's a remote server and you need SSH access: Don't lock yourself out. Make sure that your SSH port is allowed or the ufw service is **not** enabled so that you can simply restart your server if things go wrong.